# Attempt to assign property "RoundNumber" on array

Tags: json, laravel

I'm trying to extract RoundNumber data from a json file that I pass from request in my laravel application in this way:

```
public function importResults(Request $request)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($request->file('results'));
    $decoded = json_decode($json);

    $roundNumber = $decoded->data->MatchingTables->RoundNumber;

    return $roundNumber;
    //return redirect('getPanel');
}
```

this is my json:

```json
"MatchingTables": [{
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "Team1": "xPn5sTmNcwZwA9XA",
            "Team2": null,
            "GameWins2": 0,
            "GameWins1": 0,
            "GameByes2": 0,
            "GameByes1": 0,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "Player1": null,
            "Player2": null,
            "Number": null,
            "Timestamp": 1676536691086,
            "MatchOrdinal": null,
            "_id": "5r14sENZ4LPyYp0Y"
        },
        {
            "Number": 3,
            "Timestamp": 1676536642961,
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "Team1": "BtjUYtJKqB1DswuF",
            "Team2": "a0M2B44mfw6zgJPh",
            "Player1": "hFXO7VhvuB6dc9u4",
            "Player2": "yyCW3cTW3lbf3HP8",
            "GameWins1": null,
            "GameWins2": null,
            "GameByes1": null,
            "GameByes2": null,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "MatchOrdinal": 3,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "_id": "7CgcJdgQJj3QpR7Z"
        },
        {
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "Team1": "QtlYSLJ4RI9tUc09",
            "Team2": null,
            "GameWins2": null,
            "GameWins1": null,
            "GameByes2": null,
            "GameByes1": 1,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "Player1": null,
            "Player2": null,
            "Number": null,
            "Timestamp": 1676536688524,
            "MatchOrdinal": null,
            "_id": "PX8gLrgQ38RmOCUO"
        },
        {
            "Number": 1,
            "Timestamp": 1676536642961,
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "Team1": "ZbBlDh1Uyt3e8Uvf",
            "Team2": "is01LkEzsWDtLTPv",
            "Player1": "62da1vAAK6z8bbxR",
            "Player2": "HPT4CJ8YM98WoqX3",
            "GameWins1": null,
            "GameWins2": null,
            "GameByes1": null,
            "GameByes2": null,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "MatchOrdinal": 1,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "_id": "QWs3NXYofMS2dcKZ"
        },
        {
            "Number": null,
            "Timestamp": 1676536642961,
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "Team1": "92Wlqmulw5YdtATz",
            "Player1": "iuv4J5dIlSo7LMfX",
            "Player2": null,
            "GameWins1": null,
            "GameWins2": null,
            "GameByes1": 1,
            "GameByes2": null,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "MatchOrdinal": 5,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "_id": "eEEBX2dg5c8V5E1z"
        },
        {
            "Number": 2,
            "Timestamp": 1676536642961,
            "RoundNumber": 1,
            "Team1": "b4nenH6nO8mk2fr0",
            "Team2": "S65ushxkZAF53bZn",
            "Player1": "DaFDCZdVNWkizy6N",
            "Player2": "SFamW9qeVlVvoAq4",
            "GameWins1": null,
            "GameWins2": null,
            "GameByes1": null,
            "GameByes2": null,
            "GameDraws": null,
            "MatchOrdinal": 2,
            "id_round": "JLLcrGFKokzyP147",
            "_id": "oiXAZVsV5zevpPvi"
        }],
```

I want to extract the "RoundNumber" property from every element of array.
I've tryed also in this ways:

```php
$roundNumber = $decoded->data->MatchingTables["RoundNumber"];
$roundNumber = $decoded->data->MatchingTables[]->RoundNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract data like that inside an array, you either specify which key from the array you want to extract or get all the values by looping or using laravel collection before getting `RoundNumber` value.

e.i You can use [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections) and [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck)

This will give you an array of values which key you pass

```
return collect( $decoded->data->MatchingTables)->pluck('RoundNumber');
```